# `this` binding in function defined in other file

Tags: javascript, react-native

i have this two files Home.js and route.js, in routes.js there's a function defined called componentToRoute, this function returns a JSX component. In the Home.js file this function is imported and called, what i want to do is to keep the `this` binding inside the componentToRoute function as well. I tried doing this with Function.prototype.call() and Function.prototype.bind() but it doesn't work.

routes.js

```
export function componentToRoute(route) {
  return (
    <View>
      <SearchInput
        section={route.title}
        onInput={this.filterArray(route.key)}></SearchInput>
      <ListOfEntries
        style={style.list}
        onEntryPress={item =>
          this.props.navigation.navigate('Local', {
            item: item,
          })
        }
        list={this.state[route.key]}></ListOfEntries>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Home.js

```
import {componentToRoute} from './routes';

class Home extends Component {

filterArray = array => text => {
    this.setState(previousState => {
      return {
        [array]: this.fitlerService.filter(
          previousState['initial' + array],
          'name',
          text,
        ),
      };
    });
  };

renderScene = ({route}) => {
    return componentToRoute(route).call(this);
  };
}
```

When the renderScene function is executed it throws `this.filterArray is undefined`, however, if i assing the function to an attribute inside the Home class like :

`componentRoute = componentToRoute;`

and then call `this.componentRoute(route)`, the function works correctly (`this` is binded to the correct object).

Do you have any idea why neither call() and bind() work correctly in this case?

Comment: You cannot use an arrow function here. With a normal function declaration, `call` will work.

Comment: componentToRoute is not an arrow function, its declared using the `function` keyword

Comment: Oops, sorry, I thought this was about `filterArray`. You're right.

Comment: define a simple method() and inside constructor bind the context this.method = this.method.bind(this);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> componentToRoute(route).call(this);
> ```
>
> Do you have any idea why neither call() and bind() work correctly in this case?

The correct syntax to use `call` here is

```
componentToRoute.call(this, route);
```

If the `componentToRoute(route)` call (in which `this` was not bound, because it's just a plain function call) wouldn't already have thrown the error about `this.filterArray`, you would have gotten an exception about the call result not having a `.call` method - you are returning the JSX object.